# How to use Guava ArrayTable to create a two dimensional table?

Tags: java, guava

I saw a lot of number of Guava hashbasedtable. Is there any ArrayTable example for reference, like how to create a ArrayTable?

Answer (score 2):

To create an `ArrayTable` use either of the static `create()` methods.

The [first](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html#create(java.lang.Iterable,java.lang.Iterable)) creates an empty table with the given rows and columns, e.g.:

```
ArrayTable.create(ImmutableList.of(1, 2, 3), ImmutableList.of('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

The [second](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html#create(com.google.common.collect.Table)) is essentially a copy-constructor, and copies the rows, columns, and values from the given table:

```
ArrayTable.create(new ImmutableTable.Builder<Integer, Character, String>()
       .put(1, 'A', "foo")
       .put(1, 'B', "bar")
       .put(2, 'A', "baz")
       .build())
```